# RelativeLayout is not called onDraw even using setWillNotDraw(false) on constructor

Tags: java, android

i created a subclass from RelativeLayout and when i call invalidate method, he's  not calling the OnDraw mehtod, here's my code:

```
        handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == GameGlobals.UpdateDraw){
                gameHandler.invalidate();
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

                    Button btt_start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btt_start);

    btt_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                setContentView(gameHandler);//The sub class from RelativeLayout

                try {
                    gameHandler.setup(handler);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showAlert(e.getMessage());
                }

                Thread thread = new Thread(gameHandler);
                thread.run();
        }
    });
```

And now the subclass:

```
    //this method is called int the three constructors
    private void setup(){
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

        @Override//from Runnable
public void run() {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = GameGlobals.UpdateLogic;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

        @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.drawText("testing..", 90, 90, textInfo);

    canvas.restore();
}
```

ok, that's all, i have debugged the code and what i see is: the onDraw method is called only two times: when it is created and then when the invalidate method is called for the first time, that's all, he don't keep calling the invalidate, this is a thread! the method run is over there, so why he is not getting called anymore?? i'll thank your help

Answer (score 0):

There's no loop in your run() method .. so it triggers the invalidate call once, sleeps for 10 msecs and then exits.

Comment: uoou. yes i forget this, now the loop on 'run' works, but the 'draw' method is not being called and the app is trapped in a loop that make it crash after a short time, he's not even leavng the current COntentView of the activity